# How to use iOS subscription promo codes with react-native-iap?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, react-native-iap

I've made Apple in-app-subscriptions. And it works successfully. And then I try to work with promotional codes, but it doesn't work.

If I understood correctly, I have to use this method:

```
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';
...
RNIap.presentCodeRedemptionSheetIOS();
```

This code opens a request window. And when I enter the correct code, a message appears with the text "You must enter a valid code."

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine now. I just created promo codes in the wrong place.

Here is the doc: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev6a098e4b1

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the whole implementation please ?

Comment: @Artur can you share the implementation?

Comment: Just use method RNIap.presentCodeRedemptionSheetIOS() instead RNIap.getProducts(...). This is all. Unfortunately, there is no way or API to find out if the subscription was paid for or received by code.